# uncaught typeerror: object [object Object] has no method 'onmouse'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I run a page and get this error:

```
 Uncaught typeerror: object [object Object] has no method 'onmouse'
```

The code it is referring to is below:

```
 $('.firsttext').onmouse(function () { $('.textinline.hover').show() });
```

My guess is that whatever .firsttext is being used on doesn't have an onmouse event but maybe a onClick, but I don't have a .firsttext or a .textinline running on the page. Although it could be in my CSS attached to something somewhere. Not sure how to figure out which method it is talking about.

Comment: try `$('.firsttext').mouseenter(...`

Comment: not sure, this code was copied from someone who previously worked on it

Comment: There are `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `click`, and `dblclick`. Check what you need.

Comment: same for this one, uncaught typeerror:object[object Object] has no method whatever, down, up, click, leave, same error for all

Comment: so none of these worked. Since this is the case what else could cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event as "onmouse", even in plain JS; perhaps you meant "onmouseover"? See [MDN Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) or [jQuery mouse events category](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

You then need to use the appropriate jQuery equivalent to bind the event (which won't begin with "on"; e.g. [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)) or use the generic [`.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (which I tend to think is clearer) - or in earlier versions of jQuery, [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: it was .hover, thanks for the link! Just need to understand how these alerts work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this:

```
$('.firsttext').on('mouseover', function () { $('.textinline.hover').show() });
```

The jQuery `on` function attaches an event handler to the selected element. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: same for this one, uncaught typeerror:object[object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @Keith Are you using jQuery >= 1.7?

Comment: yeah 1.7, it was .hover

Comment: $('.firsttext').hover(function () { $('.textinline.hover').show() });

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use CSS only?
`.firsttext:hover .textinline{display:block;}` or something similar? 
(.textinline has to be a child of .firsttext, though)